# Is there a possibility to change the color of the button?

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, ionic2

I want that the button's color change when the user wrote his username and pw into the input, so as a sign of the button can be pressed know. (so change of grey -> green)

CSS

```
   .turn-green {
    background-color: green;
}
```

TS

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {
  userWroteName: false;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    function userTyped(value) { // fires on each keystroke
    const minLengthForName = 3; // you choose your min accepted length
    // some code you want here
    if (value.length >= minLengthForName) {
        this.userWroteName = true;
    } else { 
        this.userWroteName = false; 
    }
}


  }



  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
  }


}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). _The_ button? - _which_ button? Add code to your question. What have you tried so far? Is it angularjs (v1) or is it ionic2 which uses typescript and Angular2+, your tags do not make sense.

Comment: The question was obvious. He needs to use ngClass to change the button's color on some condition. People can spend hours looking for how to do simple things like this and comments like "you didn't do enough" are not helpful. We've all been there. It's not like he asked how to initialize an int or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `*.html` file on your `<button>` element use `[ngClass]`

```
<button [ngClass]="{'turn-green': userWroteName}">My Button</button>
```

In your `*.css` file define the `turn-green` class

```
.turn-green {
    background-color: green;
}
```

In your `*.ts` file create the boolean variable `userWroteName` and then have some function that fires based on whether or not the user wrote something in the textbox.

```
userWroteName: false;

function userTyped(value) { // fires on each keystroke
    const minLengthForName = 3; // you choose your min accepted length
    // some code you want here
    if (value.length >= minLengthForName) {
        this.userWroteName = true;
    } else { 
        this.userWroteName = false; 
    }
}
```

This code assumes you are listening to each keystroke, and calling `userTyped()` on each keystroke being typed.

Comment: so I write  userWroteName: false; in the export class and the rest In the constructor? Because now it doesn't happen anything. if I do it like this.

Comment: It does not go into the constructor. It's a separate function in the *.ts file. Do you have a listener on your input field?

Comment: no I'm sorry I don't know what that is:( But I can google it quickly.

Comment: you have probably defined an <input type="text"> somewhere in your html, which creates your text field. add a couple of things here: <input type='text' #userInput (keyup)="userTyped(userInput.value)"> This is a listener for your keystrokes that will call the function userTyped and pass it the current value that's in the box.

Comment: ok I've done that now, thx. And now one last question: the variable and the function to the *.ts file? So which one is that: components.ts, module.ts, main.ts, login.ts, login.module.ts ? Sorry for the many questions but I'm quite new to Ionic

Comment: Your component file, wherever your HTML file is the template.

Comment: By the way, ngClass is Angular 4.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it worked. You can used the disabled property on the button as well to stop clicks.